# IS VS and .NET Fragmented just like android?

Tags: .net, wpf, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have been using ASP.NET to develop web apps for sometime now(around 4 years). But all of a sudden I feel .NET and VS is too fragmented. Say for example there are WinForms and WPF to develop windows apps and Web Forms and MVC to develop web apps. I know its a choice that devs have to make. But sometimes I feel there are too many technologies to master in .NET framework and the list seems to continue with time.

Comments welcome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More tools are better than less tools. Is programming becoming too fragmented because there are so many programming languages? Choice is a great thing. You aren't required to know the whole suite of tools. If you do .NET desktop development, you can choose between WinForms or the newer WPF. WPF skills can transfer over to Silverlight web development. WinForms users can learn WPF. Two technologies is hardly a major concern, especially considering many of the skills (libraries and language) are nearly 100% transferable.

WebForms are fairly dated, and ASP MVC is a completely new direction for the .NET stack which is very encouraging.

I'd be worried if nothing new was coming out. Microsoft is ensuring that the skills you currently have with .NET will still be relevant in quite a few years. If nothing new was coming out, someone else would do it, and you'd have to learn new tech from the bottom up.

I learnt enough WPF to get by in about 2 to 3 weeks. I felt comfortable with ASP MVC in all of 3 days.

I think .NET is hitting the sweet spot with most of their new(er) tech.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way that .NET gets fragmented is if we see version of the .NET framework not being supported on servers.

In my experience, this has not been the case in any of my work environments.

Android is fragmented because the 'devices' themselves are not supporting updated versions of the Android OS.

I don't consider multiple tools to do the job 'fragmentation'.

Comment: I agree, But dont you think there are so many tools in .NET and VS that can do the same job??

Comment: I think its starting to get to that point.  I think that's one of the big problems with Java in some organizations.  The nice thing with .NET has always been that developers could be plugged in and they would be familiar with the toolset, sdks, etc..   Now with ASP.NET MVC and multiple view engines, WCF, WPF, etc... there is tons of flexibility but does create a knowledge gap because you cannot expect developers to be experts of the entire suite of toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is the case. In general it all boils down to what is available today + what is the way for the future. 

 e.g. 

Desktop Development: A few years ago it was Winforms all the way. Now its WPF all the way. But in the middle (VS 2008) WPF wasn't ready enough so you could chose either (future safe or greater community). 

 Web Development: Webforms is on its way out. MVC is on its way in. 

 Database Development: Linq 2 SQL is now out for new apps. Entity framework is the way to go. 

 and on and on and on. There are however always non MS options to chose from. That is a good thing. e.g. NHibernate is great because you can migrate the experience you have from Hibernate plus additional non MS databases are better supported. This shows maturity of .NET. Don't be afraid of it. Embrace it! It all boils down to what features you want.